# Facebook Like/Share (Mostly) not working on my Wordpress blog

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

Facebook LIKE/SHARE functions are generally not working on my wordpress blog. I cannot LIKE or SHARE any new posts, but oddly if I have already LIKED a page, the SHARE function works fine.

The problem with SHARE is that the normal sharing window pops up, but there is no metadata populated in it.  I've looked at the metadata in my blog posts and as best I can tell it is populated correctly by Wordpress.  Additionally, I cannot find any differences in the metadata or code between posts that I have previously LIKED and ones that I have have not.

I've tried running the FB debugger/linter for a number of posts on my site and each one returns the message: 
**Error Linting URL:    An internal error occurred while linting the URL.**

I've tried googling this error, but cannot find any useful advice on what might be causing it.

Here is a sample post for people to examine this problem:

http://erb.kingdomnow.org/michael-pollan-talks-about-his-new-book-cooked-video/

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Open Graph tags (see "[Use proper Open Graph tags and large images to generate great previews](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#tags)" and "[Using Self-Hosted Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/)") in the header of your webpages to help Facebook determine what metadata needs to be shared.

Since you are using WordPress, you could either edit the template file in your theme that defines page headers (normally `header.php`) or use [Facebook's official plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/).

Comment: Thx, Martey.  Issue now resolved, and your reply pointed me in the right direction.  The issue was with the OG tags, but apparently the Socialize plugin was populating them insufficiently.   I added the **WP Facebook Open Graph protocol** plugin, which populated the OG tags correctly (and in a much more streamlined fashion than FB's official plugin), and then deactivated the Socialize plugin.